# Detect specific CSS3 Keyframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

How to detect that the animation reached a specific keyframe? (For example 50% or 75%).

This is what I tried:

```
element.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationListener, false);
```

but it supports animationstart, animationiteration and animationend only.

http://jsfiddle.net/W3y7h/294/

Comment: As far as I know the only option is to use a timer and use your own calculations. Just checked the specs, there seems to be a `elapsedTime` attribute but still it would just tell you the time, what percentage it represents would still need calculations.

Comment: Please provide a woking example of your animation.

Comment: @Shaggy have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: @Beckham: sorry, don't know how I missed that!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ has some helpful insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example Fiddle provided, what you're essentially looking to know is when the value of `#sun` element's `bottom` property is equal to `100px`. You can do this by using [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to check that value, clearing the interval when it is equal to `100px` and then executing whatever code you wish, like so:

```js
var style=window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("sun")),
 interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("bottom"))===100){
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("50% reached");
        }
    },1);
```

```css
#sun{
    animation:sunrise 1s ease;
    bottom:0;
    background:#ff0;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
}
@keyframes sunrise{
    0%{
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
    50%{
        bottom:100px;
    }
    100%{
        bottom:0;
        left:400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="sun"></div>
```

To check for multiple values, simply set a new interval. In the case of your example, the value of the `bottom` property should be `50px` when the animation is 75% complete. That being said, it may not always be exactly `50px` in every browser so, instead, given that we know the value of the `bottom` property will be decreasing at this point, instead check for it being less than or equal to 50:

```js
var style=window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("sun")),
 interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("bottom"))===100){
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("50% reached");
            interval=setInterval(function(){
                if(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("bottom"))<=50){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log("75% reached");
                }
            },1);
        }
    },1);
```

```css
#sun{
    animation:sunrise 1s ease;
    bottom:0;
    background:#ff0;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
}
@keyframes sunrise{
    0%{
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
    50%{
        bottom:100px;
    }
    100%{
        bottom:0;
        left:400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="sun"></div>
```