# Detect CSS Animation Keyframes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-animations, keyframe

So I have a simple CSS animation (a circle that grows, and then shrinks back down). I am able to successfully use Javascript to detect the start and end of the animation, but can't figure out how to detect the individual keyframes of that animation.

So my question is: how can I detect when the 50% keyframe has been reached in my animation?

Demo: http://codepen.io/tymichaels/pen/Mprrxw

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <svg class="center circle-animation" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/">
        <g>
            <circle cx="65" cy="70" r=60 fill="#96CCFF" stroke-width="3" stroke="#8181F7"></circle>
            <text x="35" y="75" font-size="18" class="output">circle</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
svg { width:150px;}

text {color:#000; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;}

.center{
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}  

.circle-animation{
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: circle-animation;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-animation {
    0% {transform: scale( 1 );}
    50% {transform: scale( 2.25 );}
    100% {transform: scale( 1 );}
}
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.circle-animation');
    var op = document.querySelector('.output');

    elm.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
        op.innerHTML = 'ended';
    });

    elm.addEventListener('animationstart', function(e) {
        op.innerHTML = 'started';
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653207/detect-specific-css3-keyframe-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You can dispatch a custom event on `animationstart` with `setInterval` and clear the interval on `animationend`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.circle-animation');
    var op = document.querySelector('.output');
    var eventOnAnimate = new Event('onanimate');
    var time = 0;

    elm.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
        op.innerHTML = 'ended';
        clearInterval(elm.interval);
        time = 0;
    });

    elm.addEventListener('animationstart', function(e) {
        op.innerHTML = 'started';
        time = 0;
        elm.interval = setInterval(function(){
          eventOnAnimate.data = {sampleData: ++time};
          elm.dispatchEvent(eventOnAnimate);
        });
    });
    
    elm.addEventListener('onanimate', function(e) {
        op.innerHTML = e.data.sampleData + 'ms';
    });
}
```

```css
svg { width:150px;}

text {color:#000; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;}

.center{
    margin-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}  

.circle-animation{
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: circle-animation;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-animation {
    0% {transform: scale( 1 );}
    50% {transform: scale( 2.25 );}
    100% {transform: scale( 1 );}
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <svg class="center circle-animation" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/">
        <g>
            <circle cx="65" cy="70" r=60 fill="#96CCFF" stroke-width="3" stroke="#8181F7"></circle>
            <text x="35" y="75" font-size="18" class="output">circle</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no native event support for listening keyframe-by-keyframe, but you can create a workaround with `setTimeout` and `window.getComputedStyle` (to get the `animation-duration` property).

Below is an `onKeyframes` utility which can be used to listen for an arbitrary number of keyframe events using a more intuitive percentage-based syntax:

```
onKeyframes(elm, {
  0: function() {
    op.textContent = 'started'
  },
  50: function() {
    op.textContent = 'midpoint'
  },
  100: function() {
    op.textContent = 'ended'
  }
})
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
function onKeyframes(element, handlers) {
  var from = handlers[0] || handlers.from
  var to = handlers[100] || handlers.to
  delete handlers.from
  delete handlers[0]
  delete handlers.to
  delete handlers[100]

  handlers = Object.keys(handlers).map(function(k) {
    return [k, this[k]]
  }, handlers)

  element.addEventListener('animationstart', function() {
    from && from.apply(this, arguments)
    if (handlers.length) {
      var match = /(\d+)(m?)s/.exec(window.getComputedStyle(element).animationDuration)
      var duration = (match[2] ? 1 : 1e3) * match[1]
      handlers.forEach(function(pair) {
        setTimeout(pair[1], pair[0] / 100 * duration)
      })
    }
  })
  to && element.addEventListener('animationend', to)
}

window.onload = function() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.circle-animation')
  var op = document.querySelector('.output')

  onKeyframes(elm, {
    0: function() {
      op.textContent = 'started'
    },
    50: function() {
      op.textContent = 'midpoint'
    },
    100: function() {
      op.textContent = 'ended'
    }
  })
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
}

text {
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.circle-animation {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: circle-animation;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale( 2.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <svg class="center circle-animation" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/">
        <g>
            <circle cx="65" cy="70" r=60 fill="#96CCFF" stroke-width="3" stroke="#8181F7"></circle>
            <text x="35" y="75" font-size="18" class="output">circle</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```